# SQL QUERY with subquery Optimization

Tags: sql

how can i optimize these query

```
SELECT
mp.ProviderName
,(SELECT count(mc.ClaimSubmissionID) FROM dbo.MST_Claim mc WHERE   mc.HeaderID=mpach.HeaderID AND mc.IsActive=1) AS total_claim
,(SELECT count(mc.ClaimSubmissionID) FROM dbo.MST_Claim mc WHERE mc.HeaderID=mpach.HeaderID AND mc.op=1) AS total_op
,(SELECT count(mc.ClaimSubmissionID) FROM dbo.MST_Claim mc WHERE mc.HeaderID=mpach.HeaderID AND mc.ip=1) AS total_ip

FROM dbo.MST_PriorAuthorization_Claim_Header mpach
INNER JOIN dbo.MS_Provider mp ON mp.Provider_ID = mpach.Provider_ID
```

Comment: please show us the structure of the tables involved..

Answer (score 1):

Use Sum of `CASE Statements` to avoid all those subqueries.

```
SELECT
    mp.ProviderName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN mc.IsActive=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS total_claim,
    SUM(CASE WHEN mc.op=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS total_op,
    SUM(CASE WHEN mc.ip=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS total_ip
FROM dbo.MST_PriorAuthorization_Claim_Header mpach
    INNER JOIN dbo.MS_Provider mp ON mp.Provider_ID = mpach.Provider_ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.MST_Claim mc ON  mc.HeaderID=mpach.HeaderID
```

Comment: i tried these one but my problem is i have to use group by with provider name then my result is going wrong

Comment: I've frequently used `GROUP BY` that way. I don't follow how results would be wrong. Besides this was not mentioned in your individual question.

Comment: You should post a new question if your `GROUP BY` clause is giving you  unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your query using a `CASE` statement like below

```
SELECT
mp.ProviderName
,sum(case when mc.IsActive=1 then mc.ClaimSubmissionID else 0 end) AS total_claim,
sum(case when mc.op=1 then mc.ClaimSubmissionID else 0  end) AS total_op
sum(case when mc.ip=1 then mc.ClaimSubmissionID else 0  end) AS total_ip

FROM dbo.MST_PriorAuthorization_Claim_Header mpach
INNER JOIN dbo.MS_Provider mp ON mp.Provider_ID = mpach.Provider_ID
JOIN dbo.MST_Claim mc ON mc.HeaderID = mpach.HeaderID;
```